# Hangfire background job mysteriously stops running

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, background-process, jobs, hangfire

I have one odd issue with Hangfire 1.4.3.0 (WebAPI, SQL server storage) - after exactly 30 mins since job started, hangfire restarts it and assigns a new worker. Default hangfire logging at trace level doesn't show anything useful. In my web app logs I can only see that job started and State table in hangfire database shows that new worker assigned:

```
Id  JobId   Name    Reason  CreatedAt   Data
27  8   Processing  NULL    2017-05-17 10:34:51.640 {"StartedAt":"2017-05-17T10:34:51.6389278Z","ServerId":"mypc:3332","WorkerNumber":"22"}
28  8   Processing  NULL    2017-05-17 11:04:51.683 {"StartedAt":"2017-05-17T11:04:51.6819303Z","ServerId":"mypc:3332","WorkerNumber":"14"}
```

But what happened to previous worker? How I can find out why it stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is known bug: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/514

Hangfire is currently on version 1.6.12 - have you tried updating to the latest version and checking if you still get the issue?

Answer (score 5):

After searching so much in the google for the same issue, I got solution from the below link, in which mentioned some configuration part which is very much important for running your job continuously.

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

-----below is the configuration you have to do in  global applicationHost.config file (%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config).

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>

<!-- ... -->

<sites>
    <site name="MySite" id="1">
        <application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true"
                              serviceAutoStartProvider="ApplicationPreload" />
    </site>
</sites>

<!-- Just AFTER closing the `sites` element AND AFTER `webLimits` tag -->
<serviceAutoStartProviders>
    <add name="ApplicationPreload" type="WebApplication1.ApplicationPreload, WebApplication1" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

Comment: Updating `applicationHost.config` is indeed *required* in order to have a .NET app always running. An example on how I noticed that on a project I'm working on: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1327